# How can I change my PHP login script with URL direction based on username and password?

Tags: php, login-script

I have a basic php login script.  I have three fields:  "username", "password", and "url".  I would like to redirect each user to their own url based on their username and password combination.  I don;t know how to incorporate the "url" into my script.

Here is my check_login.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="myusername"; // Mysql username
$password="mypassword"; // Mysql password
$db_name="naturan8_login"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or
die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and 
password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
header("location:error.htm");
}
?>
```

Comment: How is the URL obtained? Is it a column in the database?

Comment: Yes, it is in the Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the following code:

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword");
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
```

...to:

```
$user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if( isset($user_info['url']) ) {

    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword");
    header('Location: ' . $user_info['url']); //Redirects to the supplied url from the DB
}
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for!

Comment: I got this:  Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/naturan8/public_html/onepack/src/php/login/check_login.php:1) in /home1/naturan8/public_html/onepack/src/php/login/check_login.php on line 37

Comment: Did you put your login-check at the top of your document? The reason that you're getting the "headers already sent"-warning is because you're "outputting" information on the page before the header()-call.

Comment: Did you put your login-check at the top of your document?  Don't understand what doc...

Comment: Oh shoot, my bad - please edit the IF-clause into reading `if( isset($user_info['url']) ) {` - I accidently checked if [0] is set, but it won't be as we're using an associative array.

Comment: ERROR:   Warning: session_register() [function.session-register]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home1/naturan8/public_html/onepack/src/php/login/check_login.php:1) in /home1/naturan8/public_html/onepack/src/php/login/check_login.php on line 33

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/naturan8/public_html/onepack/src/php/login/check_login.php:1) in /home1/naturan8/public_html/onepack/src/php/login/check_login.php on line 35

Comment: Could you paste the code in `check_login.php` to `pastebin.com`? There's some output that's getting in the way.

Comment: I just pasted it to the requested url under the name check_login.php.  Erik

Comment: Try this instead: http://pastebin.com/Wh6RDvfz (note that I've removed the tab that you had before your `<?php`).

Comment: It works.  Thank you.  Is it possible to redirect to a protected subdomain with the same username and password?

Comment: If you protect it with .htpasswd - not that I'm aware of, as it's an other way of authenticating a  user. Just add a check to see if the session is active; if not, redirect them to error.htm!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. `session_register` is deprecated. Use `$_SESSION['username'] = $username` instead.
2. You probably shouldnt store the password in the session, you have the username or userid and that should be enough.
3. With the session data, you could customize the login_success page to each user without creating seperate pages. All you need to do is look at the `$_SESSION['username']` var to see who it is. (Make sure you can `session_start()` on all pages where you intent to read/write session data.

Comment: Thank you.  Its above my head.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_result() to extract the url field from the query:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

```
$url = mysql_result($result, $x); // $x is the column number of the url field.
```

`header("location: {$url}");`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `header("location:login_success.php");` with

```
$user =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
header("location:{$user['url']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Query this:

`$sql="SELECT url FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and 
password='$mypassword' LIMIT 1";`

Then where you redirect, replace it with:

`header("Location: " . mysql_result($sql, 0));`